# Wordpress function - Log claims variable undefined

Tags: php, wordpress

I get the following undefined variable error in my php log but it's clearly defined in the function below. Am I doing something wrong?

```
 [18-Sep-2013 15:17:23 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: the_limit in /Volumes/Mac HD/Sites/thesite/wp-content/themes/site2.7/functions.php on line 313

 class EditorsPicks extends WP_Widget{
    function __construct()
    {
        $params=array(
            'description' => 'Editors Picks',
            'name'        => 'Editors Picks'            );

        parent::__construct('EditorsPicks','',$params);
    }

    public function form($instance)
    {
        extract($instance);

        // Title
        echo '<p><label for="'.$this->get_field_id('title').'">Title:</label>';
        echo '<input class="widefat" id="'.$this->get_field_id('title').'" name="'.$this->get_field_name('title').'"';
        echo 'value="';
        echo !empty($title) ? esc_attr($title) : 'Editor\'s Picks';
        echo '"/></p>';

        // Category
        echo '<p><label for="'.$this->get_field_id('category').'">Category ID:</label>';
        echo '<input class="widefat" type="number" id="'.$this->get_field_id('category').'" name="'.$this->get_field_name('category').'" value="';
        echo !empty($category) ? esc_attr($category) : 75646;
        echo '"/></p>';

        // Limit
        echo '<p><label for="'.$this->get_field_id('the_limit').'">Limit:</label>';
        echo '<input class="widefat" type="number" id="'.$this->get_field_id('the_limit').'" name="'.$this->get_field_name('the_limit').'" value="';
        echo !empty($the_limit) ? esc_attr($the_limit) : 5;
        echo '"/></p>';
    }

    function widget($args,$instance){
        extract($args);
        extract($instance);

        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title.$title.$after_title;

        global $post;
        $editors_picks=get_posts(array('cat'=>$category,'posts_per_page'=>$the_limit));

        echo '<ul class="editors_picks">';
        foreach($editors_picks as $post) : setup_postdata($post);
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),array(236,190));

            echo '<li class="clickable">';
            echo '<a rel="nofollow" href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'"><img width="100" height="81" src="'.$image[0].'" alt="'.get_the_title().'"/></a>';
            echo '<div class="title"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">'.textLimit(get_the_title(),80).'</a></div>';
            echo '</li>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</ul>';
        echo $after_widget;
    }
 }
```

Comment: check the widget function, see the args or instance array contain th the limit key, probably they don't that's why in the widget function's scope the variable is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the function form, $title, $category, $the_limit are NOT explicitly defined. they will only be defined if they are key/value entries in the $instance array. Your best bet will be to var_dump($instance) to see if your the_limit is in there.